# Creation of many to many record through process builder/flow/apex?

Tags: apex, process-builder, visual-workflow

When field `review_date__c` on object `knowledge_article__c` changes to a specific date, it should create a new record on object `Incident__c`. I have achieved this with process builder.

However I then wish to be able to create a `Knowledge_Incident_Link__c` record and link the  `knowledge_article__c` record with the `Incident__c`. Ideally I'd like to do this with another process, but what are my options? How can I implement this idea? What steps would I need to take?

Below are the object relationships.

[image]

Comment: You need to use Flow if you want to do this in all 1 step. You cant do SOQL in Process Builder and you'd need to do that to use the ID of the record you just created.